beautiful soup find all not finding div AFTER button click
I'm trying to scrap this website.
The issue occurs when I try to scrap the data related to the car equipment grid. I'm able to extract only the elements that are already shown in the page, even if, I click on the button to show them all.
In conclusion, I'm not able to get the elements that are shown AFTER the button click event.
I noticed that are flagged on the inspection element tab of the browser as "event" but I don't know how to use that information with bs4.
Here is the code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_settings.cookies": 2})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

url='https://www.autoscout24.it/ricerca-avanzata?sort=standard&desc=0&ustate=N,U&atype=C&cy=I&mmm=13||&lat=45.5714&lon=12.10799&zip=30037-scorz%C3%A8&zipr=100&source=homepage_search-mask'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'_consent-accept_1fb0r_111').click()

for i in range(2):
    driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/button").click()

h=requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(h, 'html.parser')
l=soup.find_all("div",{"class": "OptionalEquipmentFilter_optionContainer__HsU8p"})
print(len(l))
accl=[]
for i in l:
    accl.append(i.span.text)
print(accl)

I don't know how to improve it.
I have some suspection that the page's source transfered to scrap session isn't updated after the button click event.
Thank you for your time :)

You can try to load the page with the results directly with requests:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.autoscout24.it/lst/bmw/30037-scorz%c3%a8"

params = {
    "atype": "C",
    "cy": "I",
    "desc": "0",
    "eq": "132,161",   # <--- equipment "CD", "USB"
    "lat": "45.5714",
    "lon": "12.10799",
    "sort": "standard",
    "source": "detailsearch",
    "ustate": "N,U",
    "zipr": "100",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params).content, "html.parser")

for article in soup.select("article"):
    title = article.h2.text
    price = article.select_one('[data-testid="regular-price"]').text
    print(title)
    print(price)
    print("-" * 80)

Prints:
...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BMW 316 - 316d Sport
€ 16.500,-
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BMW 320 2.0 PER COMMERCIANTI
€ 1.800,-
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BMW 318 i Business Advantage
€ 17.800,-
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BMW M2 M240i 340cv AUT VOLANTE CARBONIO MPERFORMANCE
€ 37.750,-
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...

